# How do I get the assigned values for enum members?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

The following code returns One, Two, Three, where I expect GetNames to do that and GetValues to return 2, 5, 10:

```
enum Nums
{
  One = 2,
  Two = 5,
  Three = 10 
}

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    var vals = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Nums));
  }
}
```

What is up here? How do I get the values 2, 5, 10 from the type `Nums`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast it to an int:

```
int val = (int)Nums.One;
```

Or to answer your question for getting all of the items in the enum:

```
IEnumerable<int> values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Nums)).Cast<int>();
```

Answer (score 3):

cast it to an int like this:

```
int value = (int)Num;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
int[] vals = Enum
    .GetValues(typeof(Nums)) // Thus far, this is your code
    .Cast<int>()             // Cast individual elements to int
    .ToArray();              // Convert the result to array
```

[Here is a demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/DDO4B0)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully wrapped my head around C# Enums yet, but the Enum.GetValues documentation has an example that shows that casting has some very interesting and powerful effects on them.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using System;

enum SignMagnitude { Negative = -1, Zero = 0, Positive = 1 };

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SignMagnitude))) {
         Console.WriteLine("{0,3}     0x{0:X8}     {1}",
                           (int) value, ((SignMagnitude) value));
}   }
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//         0     0x00000000     Zero 
//         1     0x00000001     Positive 
//        -1     0xFFFFFFFF     Negative
```